# How do I filter a set or 'OR' results with a final 'AND' that works safely with the 'NOT EXIST' in 'OR'

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get a dataset returned for a WordPress query, and I can't get the last part working with ACF fields.

The 'OR' section works fine with it returning the set with both rows that contain the fields that exist or not.

The problem is that I can't seem to filter out the older ACF fields that are older than todays date.

The ACF fields (time) are d-m-Y format.

So basically, I want the set to return any rows from and including today - and also the rows that have no ACF populated.

I've managed to get the first part of the query working, so leaving it in there for context. I've tried various formats of the relation/arrays, but either get blank results, or ALL the rows.

```php
       $newDate = date('d-m-Y');
            $the_query = new WP_Query([
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array('key' => 'time', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'),
                    array('key' => 'time', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'),
                ),
         array( 'relation' => 'AND',
             array('key' => 'time', 'value' => $newDate, 'compare' => '>'),
             ),
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'cat' => $final_cat,
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            ]);
```

I should be getting rows without older dates, but this returns all the rows at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I found that ACF actually stores the date picker field in Ymd regardless of what you pick. With some adjustment I was able to return all fields without the date field, and those dates in the future.

```php
  $the_query = new WP_Query([
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array('key' => 'time', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'), 
                array('key' => 'time', 'value' => date('Ymd'), 'type' => 'DATE', 'compare' => '>='),
            ),
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'tag' => $sk_tag,
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ]);
```